# Android: Using linear gradient as background looks banded

Tags: android, gradient, shapes

I'm trying to apply a linear gradient to my ListView.
This is the content of my drawable xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#3A3C39" 
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:angle="270"
     />
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

So I apply it to my ListView with:

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_background_grey"
```

It works but it looks very "banded" on emulator and on a real device too.

Is there any way to reduce this "behaviour"?

Comment: Just an update: adding 
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
in the onCreate method seems does the trick also for hdpi with amoled screen (N1/Desire)

Comment: `@Francesco` Great! It helped on my **Galaxy S** with **Android 2.2**. Please convert your useful comment to an answer, so people can vote for it.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As Romain Guy suggests:

```
listView.getBackground().setDither(true);
```

solves my problem

If this is not enough especially for AMOLED and/or hdpi devices try this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Comment: This not works on android 1.6 and above. See my other comment

Comment: @Artem In my case, on Android >= 1.6 `listView.getBackground().setDither(true);` wont work, I had to override the `onAttachedToWindow` method.

Comment: setDither() is now deprecated

Answer (score 41):

You can simply enable dithering on your Drawable object.

Comment: Yes it works!
Ty very much.
BTW I tried to use this property into the drawable xml definition but as I 
read  better into the documentation, this property is supported only for the 
selector element.

Comment: Unfortunly this not works on Android version > 1.5. I tested on real device with Android 1.6 and Android 1.5. Adding dither to my drawable gradient not works. The devices are both 320 x 480 (180 ppi). Any suggestion? Tnx

Comment: `setDither()` was deprecated in API level 23. This property is now ignored.

Answer (score 9):

Put this in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the dither and RGBA_888 setting don't help on some phones, the solution can be to set the element `layerType` to `software`, to disable the hardware acceleration

```
android:layerType="software"
```

This fixed my problem on a Samsung S5 phone.

Answer (score 4):

For me on HTC Desire works like this

```
window.getDecorView().getBackground().setDither(true);
```

Comment: `setDither()` was deprecated in API level 23. This property is now ignored.

Answer (score 3):

For me the banding disappeared when I set the android:useLevel="true" on the gradient:
gradient_dark.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#464646"
        android:endColor="#323232"
        android:angle="270"
        android:type="linear"
        android:useLevel="true"
         />
</shape>
```

But first I tried using a Layer-List with a "noise" drawable to remove the banding, it helps but there is still some banding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_dark"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/noise_repeater"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The "noise_repeater" drawable i created and used

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to set a slightly-transparent alpha channel on both the startColor and endColor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#FE3A3C39" 
        android:endColor="#FE181818"
        android:angle="270"
     />
</shape>
```

I got the idea to try this from this other SO question: [android:dither=“true” does not dither, what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769885/androiddither-true-does-not-dither-whats-wrong)