# color banding solution killed after defining sdk-version in manifest

Tags: android, background, gradient, shapes

The reader can refer to this question: [android:dither="true" does not dither, what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769885/androiddither-true-does-not-dither-whats-wrong/6028652#6028652)

I had color banding too... The solution was to create an alias (in xml) with dither set to "true" for my png images with gradients. **This worked until I specified the SDK version** in my manifest file `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`...

Color banding reappeared on emulator with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and skin WVGA800

Does somebody can explain me why !?

Project files: https://rapidshare.com/files/3429393846/Dithering.zip

--

My layout and the target to its background (alias with dithering):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/d_gradient_grey_dither">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The background (d_gradient_grey_dither.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/d_gradient_grey"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"/>
```

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

See the result here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XNlR9DvXRvoyFYWVOe9wMARq0E60fkbrBy9ANADvPw4/edit?hl=fr&authkey=COvrv9EG

And the project files if it can help:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6Y0F7DEUPbPZTM5MDU0YzAtNjJiYi00NTU0LTlmNTAtMWJiZTJhNjBhYjA3&hl=fr

or (zipped)

https://rapidshare.com/files/3429393846/Dithering.zip

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use and I have used thru API 11.

```
/** -- Eliminates color banding -- **/

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
super.onAttachedToWindow();
Window window = getWindow();
window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Comment: @Gilbou  I don't recall were I got this snippet but it works for me.