# Cant get gradient backgrounds to look good?

Tags: android, screen

I've tried everything, and searched the whole web, but still, nothing works.
Here is the background my designer designed:
 [image]

And here how it looks on my screen (Galaxy S I9000):
[image]

I've tried to enable dithering with this code:

```
findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_Main).getBackground().setDither(true);
    @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, this article will be interesting for you:

[Android perfect UI: fighting with dithering](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=247)

And you can read about dithering background here on SO too

[android:dither="true" does not dither, what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769885/androiddither-true-does-not-dither-whats-wrong)

And last suggestion comes from Android Google Groups

https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/aebef48635d04334/2e3d86e62e0452e5?lnk=gst&q=dithering#2e3d86e62e0452e5

to use `gradient proxy drawable shape` instead of `@drawable/image` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/image" 
    android:dither="true" />
```