# Layout Background picture looks weird

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image

I added some background pictures to different linear layouts in my application.
 as you can see on Eclipse they all look fine.[image: Eclipse]
The problem is that on an emulator or a phone the one for the main linear layout gets messed up, does anyone know why?

[image: Emulator]

That's the code I used:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    >
```

The background is a real picture, not code:
[image: The Pic]

Comment: post some code so that we can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Using linear gradient as background looks banded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928101/android-using-linear-gradient-as-background-looks-banded)

Comment: Particularly, setting the window to RGBA_888 should look the best (and should be the default on Android 2.3+ devices anyways). Also see http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2010/06/04/android-color-banding/

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar I posted the code, don't think it will help you.

Comment: @Yoni Samlan I don't think that's my problem, as I just noted I that used a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that your image is being read into a 16-bit (RGB565) bitmap. See http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/ -- you may want to read the image from /res/raw and use a BitmapFactory to read it in at the proper depth. Also see http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html for more on that. It also might be enough to make sure to save your .png with an alpha channel, which would force the system to interpret it as 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Activity in onCreate() `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);`

Comment: Try it before `setContentView()`, but I don't thing that is the issue.