# Backgrounds look bad in phones?

Tags: android

My designer created some good looking designs but the problem is that when I apply them on the app I get a weird outcome... Here is the image he designed:
[image]

And here it is when I apply it on the phone:
[image]

Why are there like waves in the phone background?

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2928101/593709). Specially last comment at the Romain Guy's answer.

Comment: i am not sure but use px instead of dp

Comment: @AdilSoomro I set the dithering to true but I still have the same thing, how can I override onAttachedToWindow? I keep getting "The method onAttachedToWindow() of type Main must override or implement a supertype method" in my Activity..

Comment: @Omar: which API level are you using. It was available in API 5.

Comment: @AdilSoomro my Project Build Target is 1.6 (API Level 4) .. Does that mean I have to increase the build target to 2.1 to have good backgrounds?

Comment: @Omar: hmmm, Just give it a try

Comment: @AdilSoomro how Do I set the dithering to an Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Either use gradient in xml or try to increase api level ..
It may work..

Comment: You mean I dinamically create the gradient effect?  I increased the api to target android 2.1 but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

apply draw 9 patch to you image...this might help u.....