# Trying to fix color banding?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, dithering

I'm trying to get rid of the color banding on my phone. It looks like this right now:

[image]

Bad right?

I followed [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=247) tutorial (the part about Pre-Dithering) and it didn't work. That screenshot is after pre-dithering. How can I fix this? Android 2.2.1

Edit: also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928101/android-using-linear-gradient-as-background-looks-banded) but I can't get the code to work.

Ok, I added

```
 bg.getDrawable().setDither(true);
```

since the background is the drawable that is banded. That crashes my app when I try to run it. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

Comment: I am having same exact problem. I am creating a comic app and the dark images looks bad. Lots of blotchy pixels. I read this blog which will give you a nice insight but I haven't gone through it all. One solution I found from the blog is putting your resource into the /raw folder. But doesn't solve it either for me. 

http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html