# How to achieve smooth Gradient on Android?

Tags: java, android, gradient

As you can see I have a gradient and it is has very strong graduations.
How do i make it look smoother?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#0F2027"
        android:centerColor="#203A43"
        android:startColor="#2C5364" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Using linear gradient as background looks banded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928101/android-using-linear-gradient-as-background-looks-banded)